# Are there alternative online resources for hacking/reverse engineering at present?

Tags: history

Years back there were sites or online resources which had a lot of information on decompilation, software protection schemes, even reality cracking (notably by [Fr/-\vi@](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fravia))

> Apart from software security sites (and conferences) sponsored by some
>   companies, are there "alternative" (in the sense of not being sponsored
>   and the content being actually valid today) online resources that have this quality?

**NOTE:** The question **does NOT** ask for specific web addresses, but for the general state of affairs on resources as mentioned above, possibly what can be like in the future also?

Thank you

Comment: But... isn't telling you this somewhat like you asking where the self-help section is?  Much of 'hacking' is discovery and exploration... learning how things work.  Generally, those 'rare gems' have to be found, and by finding them, you show your worthiness.  (The best fishing spots are NEVER published, trust me) Enhance your Google-Fu.  When you can take the pebble from my hand, Grasshopper, you will be ready.

Comment: Back then search engines sucked. Now with a bit of creative googling you can find anything you want as long as it's on the Internet. Some people keep their own archives of good stuff - I keep a regularly updated and groomed offline database of clippings. Here's a public one by someone else: https://www.evernote.com/pub/wishi/crazylazy. The important point is you do need to explore, not wait for others to prepare a digest for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The question states precisely that no specific web addreeses or online resourcses are requested, but a view about the state of affairs of such resources (if exist) and a view towards the future (at least the close future)

Comment: As Marx said, the important thing is not just to explain the world (as philosophy tried to do until now), but to change it towards a better future